# Why are cosine and sine used to solve this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2}+\lambda u =0
$$
Why are cosine and sine used to solve this differential equation of second order?

Comment: Because it works! Solving differential equations is often about guessing and verifying a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that $u(t)$ is of the form $e^{at}$. Then $u'(t)=ae^{at}=au,\quad u''(t)=a^2e^{at}=a^2u,~$ etc. So our equation becomes $a^2u+\lambda u=0$. Dividing both sides by *u*, we have $a^2+\lambda=0,~$ implying $a=\pm~i~\sqrt\lambda.~$ But we know that $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\cdot\sin x.~$ In this case, $x=\pm\sqrt\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the mathematical theory, and assuming $\lambda >0$ since otherwise no sine/cosine is involved, this is a rough argument: you are looking for a function whose second derivative is a *negative* multiple of the function itself. Since the second derivative of the sine is *minus* the sine and the second derivative of the cosine is *minus* the cosine, it is natural to manipulate $\sin (\cdot)$ and $\cos (\cdot)$ to find a true solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$u''+\lambda u=0$$
$$2u''u'+2\lambda u'u=0$$
$$(u')^2+\lambda u^2=C$$
$$\cdots$$